# Convert High Poly Mesh to Low Poly

Tags: hair, subdivision-surface, unreal-engine

I am trying to import a hair particle system into ue4. I followed another thread that said to convert it to a mesh, then convert it to a curve, then bevel it with a shape (I used a triangle), and then convert it back to a mesh in order to import it. When I exported it, it took a very long time, and then it took a very long time to import it but just before it was done importing, UE4 crashed. I am guessing this is because it is high poly. I checked the face count and there were 7000 some odd faces. I am wondering if there is a way to convert it to low poly now. I tried the remesh modifier but that made it look very distorted. I then tried the decimate modifier but I still got the viewport lag. I then tried to go into edit mode and unsubdivide it and windows says Blender Not Responding. Is there a way to make it low poly but not distorted and doesn't make blender crash?

Edit: Just checked I have more than 9 million vertices.

Comment: Decimate is definitely your friend here.  I'd recommend 'planar' in decimate, and tune the angle to your liking.  Remesh will often make it worse.

If you've got 9 million verts in your model, you may want to just start over because that will definitely choke your PC no matter what.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I think I will start over and if I have any other problems I will come back.

Comment: Related: [How do I simplify the polygons of a 3D scanned model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/162460/78972)